# How to set idle Hive jdbc connection out from java code using hive jdbc

Tags: java, hive

I am using hive jdbc 1.0 in my java application to create connection with hive server and execute query. I want to set the idle hive connection timeout from java code. Like say, user first creates the hive connection, and if the hive connection remains idle for next 10 minutes, then this connection object should get expired. If user uses this same connection object after 10 minutes for executing query, then hive jdbc should throw error. Can you please tell me the way to achieve this through java code.

I know there is a property `hive.server2.idle.session.timeout` in hive, but I don't know whether this is the right property required to be set from java code or there is some other property. I tried setting this property in jdbc connection string but it did not worked.

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
}

String jdbcurl = "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/idw?hive.server2.idle.session.timeout=1000ms";
Connection con;
con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcurl,"root","");

Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Now below I am using connection object, hive jdbc should throw error here as I used connection object after 3000 ms but I had set the idle timeout as 1000ms but hive jdbc had not thrown error

```
ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from idw.emp");
```

Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The  hive.server2.idle.session.timeout causes a session to be terminated when it is not accessed for the specified duration. However, hive.server2.idle.session.timeout needs to be specified with hive.server2.session.check.interval set to 
a positive value. basically, we need to be specify a number of session checks within the timeout interval to cause the session to be closed.

More details can be checked here
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.server2.session.check.interval

Comment: I used both of the configuration parameter in connection string. It did not worked. jdbc:hive2://192.168.145.182:10000/;hive.server2.idle.session.timeout=5000ms;hive.server2.session.check.interval=4000ms

Comment: @ReenaUpadhyay did you find some solution for that? I have read this link and it seems useful but i haven't tried it yet http://www.ericlin.me/how-to-configue-session-timeout-in-hive
Moreover, in my case my spark application is killed after some undefined idle interval without any log indication and once it is started again my jboss server can't reconnect to it

Answer (score -1):

You are looking at the problem the wrong way. These properties are **not** set in the URL, as described in the [Hive AdminManual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration)...

In the Hadoop ecosystem, **server defaults** are set in XML config files -- in that case `/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` and/or `hiveserver2-site.xml`

Once your session is open, you can set **custom values** with the `set <prop>=<value>` statement *(somewhat similar to the Oracle ALTER SESSION)*.

Caveat: some properties are defined as "final" in the config files and cannot be overriden. Check with your Hadoop Admin if in doubt.